# Creating Trendline in R

Tags: r, graph, trendline

I have a large dataset and I would like to create a trendline graph.

One of the columns keeps years from (1950 to 2014), one keeps house salesprices and the last one keeps GrLivArea datas in it.

X axis should be salesprices and the Y should be the years or GrLivArea.

I would like to calculate average salesprices for every year then create trendline graph based on average salesprices and GrLivArea so How can I do it?

```
  > cor(train$SalePrice,train$GrLivArea)
  0.7086245
  > cor(train$SalePrice,train$YearBuilt)
  0.5228973
```

Example of data;

```
    SalePrice   GrLivArea   YearBuilt
     208500     1710         1950
     181500     1710         1950
     223500     1786         1965
     140000     1717         2000
```

Trendline formula should be like this;
First I have to calculate average for same data groups

(208500+181500)/2=195000

After Aggregate functions

```
   SalePrice    GrLivArea   YearBuilt
     195000     1710         1950
     223500     1786         1965
     140000     1717         2000
```

And the result should be Trendline graph or Bar Graph or any other graph that make sense

Comment: What errors are you getting? You should be getting a scatterplot with that code just fine.

Comment: I'm getting a nice plot. What's your error?

Comment: I added much more details to my question.